# GPO WSUS - Turns off windows update service

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, gpo

I have one GPO for WSUS service. It is used to make clients use WSUS.

But whenever I run `gpupdate /force` on the client machine it stops `Windows update servies` after 2 to 10 minutes. I have to start it manually, but it gets stopped every time `gpupdate` runs.

Any idea why GPUpdate forces the `windows update service` to stop?

[image]

Here are some of the windows update logs:

```
2023/04/04 01:00:05.7207476 1372  8080  DataStore       JetEnableMultiInstance succeeded - applicable param count: 5, applied param count: 5
2023/04/04 01:00:05.9690425 1372  8080  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2023/04/04 01:00:05.9690732 1372  8080  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.
2023/04/04 01:00:05.9696558 1372  8080  Shared          Network state: Connected
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0393137 1372  8080  Misc            *FAILED* [8024000C] LoadHistoryEventFromRegistry completed
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0399616 1372  8080  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0399832 1372  8080  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0399955 1372  8080  Shared          Power status changed
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0429056 1372  8080  Agent           Initializing global settings cache
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0429076 1372  8080  Agent           WSUS server: http://wsus.addemo.com:8530
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0429088 1372  8080  Agent           WSUS status server: http://wsus.addemo.com:8530
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0429195 1372  8080  Agent           Alternate Download Server: (null)
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0429211 1372  8080  Agent           Fill Empty Content Urls: No
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0429221 1372  8080  Agent           Target group: Non-prod
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0429231 1372  8080  Agent           Windows Update access disabled: No
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0429242 1372  8080  Agent           Do not connect to Windows Update Internet locations: No
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0434393 1372  8080  Agent               Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2023-04-05 11:38:06, not idle-only, not network-only
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0484831 1372  8080  Agent           Initializing Windows Update Agent
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0485851 1372  8080  DownloadManager Download manager restoring 0 downloads
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0486723 1372  8080  Agent           CPersistentTimeoutScheduler | GetTimer, returned hr = 0x00000000
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0493503 1372  8080  IdleTimer       IdleTimer::NetworkStateChanged. Network connected? Yes
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0598440 1372  4464  DownloadManager Received power state change notification: Old: <unknown>; New: AC.
2023/04/04 01:00:06.0598462 1372  4464  DownloadManager Power state changed from <unknown> to AC.
2023/04/04 01:06:09.0554997 1372  8080  Agent           Refreshing global settings cache
2023/04/04 01:06:09.0555021 1372  8080  Agent           WSUS server: http://wsus.addemo.com:8530 (Unchanged)
2023/04/04 01:06:09.0555036 1372  8080  Agent           WSUS status server: http://wsus.addemo.com:8530 (Unchanged)
2023/04/04 01:06:09.0555050 1372  8080  Agent           Alternate Download Server: (null) (Changed)
2023/04/04 01:06:09.0555507 1372  8080  Agent           Fill Empty Content Urls: No (Unchanged)
2023/04/04 01:06:09.0555562 1372  8080  Agent           Target group: Non-prod (Unchanged)
2023/04/04 01:06:09.0555576 1372  8080  Agent           Windows Update access disabled: No (Unchanged)
2023/04/04 01:06:09.0555590 1372  8080  Agent           Do not connect to Windows Update Internet locations: No (Unchanged)
2023/04/04 01:10:05.7269236 1372  1496  Agent           Earliest future timer found:
2023/04/04 01:10:05.7269356 1372  1496  Agent               Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2023-04-05 11:38:06, not idle-only, not network-only
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7362603 1372  8080  Shared          UninitializeSUS
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7362630 1372  8080  Misc            CSusClientGlobal::DoServicePreShutdown
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7383258 1372  8080  IdleTimer       Idle timer disabled in preparation for service shutdown
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7383374 1372  8080  Misc            WUTaskManager uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7383427 1372  8080  Agent           Earliest future timer found:
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7383515 1372  8080  Agent               Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2023-04-05 11:38:06, not idle-only, not network-only
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7416966 1372  8080  Misc            CreateSessionStateChangeTrigger, TYPE:2, Enable:No
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7417027 1372  8080  Misc            CreateSessionStateChangeTrigger, TYPE:4, Enable:No
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7451753 1372  8080  Misc            Agent uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7464528 1372  8080  Misc            Reporter uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7465485 1372  8080  Misc            network cost manager uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7465912 1372  8080  Misc            Eventer uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7467112 1372  8080  Misc            ServiceManager uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7467258 1372  8080  Misc            PersistentTimeoutScheduler uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:06.7467276 1372  8080  Misc            datastore uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:07.3533122 1372  8080  Misc            setting cache uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:07.3533156 1372  8080  Misc            security checker uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:07.3533194 1372  8080  Misc            Test Hook uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:07.3533204 1372  8080  Misc            IdleTimer uninit
2023/04/04 01:10:07.3536142 1372  8080  Shared          * END * Service exit Exit code = 0x240001
```

Update: It turns off automatically 2 minutes before the scheduled time or 10 minutes after the scheduled time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

It seems `GPUpdate /force` is managing the windows update service.

When I run `GPUpdate /force` while the `windows update service` is not running, it starts `windows update service` and turns it off later.